# Initializing a member pointer with a dynamically allocated pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

Is it possible and good practise to initialize a member pointer with a dynamically allocated pointer? Should I delete the pointer in the destructor?

```
class Apple
{
  public:
    Apple(int* counter) : counter_(counter);
    ~Apple(); // should I delete counter_ here?
  private:
    int* counter_;
}

int main()
{
  someptr = new int;
  apple_fruit = Apple(someptr);
  delete someptr;

  return 0;
}
```

I am fairly new to C++ and still have some confusion on how best to deal with dynamically allocated memory especially when its used for initialization.

Comment: You may be interested in articles about RAII and smart pointers. Regarding your question it depends on the context of your program and also it depends who has ownership of allocated resource. In your example the only one owner of the counter is Apple class. In such case it should be allocated in the constructor and deallocated in the destructor. You should also remember about defining copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators.

Comment: Don't overuse pointers, and don't use them where you don't have to. 
You might want to work through chapter M of learncpp, https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/intro-to-smart-pointers-move-semantics/ before you continue

Comment: Yes, I am currently working through smart pointers in C++ Primer. To add more context, what triggered this question is while working through the iterator design pattern here, https://github.com/Junzhuodu/design-patterns/blob/master/BehaviroalPatterns/iterator/Iterator.cxx, the ConcreteIterator constructor is called with a ConcreteAggregate pointer and I was confused whether this is a shallow or deep copy and adding to my confusion the member function createIterator() dynamically allocates memory which is never released in the destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to initialize a member pointer with a pointer to dynamically allocated data. I've seen this done in instances where a class needs access to an instance of another (dynamically allocated) class.

It's good practice only if you absolutely need to do it. If it's simply an integer we're dealing with (as in your example) then don't use a pointer and store the actual integer instead.

For deletion, do not delete the pointer in the class destructor unless it's your class that originally allocated the data. Your instinct was correct to delete it in main() because it was created in main().

Comment: Thanks, just added a comment above, while working through the iterator design pattern here https://github.com/Junzhuodu/design-patterns/blob/master/BehaviroalPatterns/iterator/Iterator.cxx,  the ConcreteIterator constructor is called with a ConcreteAggregate pointer and I was confused whether this is a shallow or deep copy and adding to my confusion the member function createIterator() dynamically allocates memory which is never released in the destructor. Is this a well constructed design pattern?

Comment: This would be an example of a shallow copy because you're assigning a pointer (if we're talking about the ConcreteIterator constructor).

The design would be better if createIterator() returned an iterator itself instead of a pointer to an iterator. That way you wouldn't even have to dynamically allocate it. 

Generally, iterators are considered to be safer alternatives to pointers. If you're using pointers to iterators, it somewhat defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I'm happy to accept your answer, I know this discussion is going off tangent, but for further clarification, how should the dynamically created pointer in createIterator() be handled? Which class should be responsible for deleting it? Also, you mentioned the ConcreteIterator constructor is a shallow copy as its assigning a pointer, does this mean that the cag_ pointer is owned by the ConcreteIterator object but distinct from the ag pointer? That is, if the cag_ is deleted this won't affect the ag pointer?

Comment: For best design, createIterator should not be returning a pointer and not be dynamically allocating memory. Instead it should return the iterator itself. But if we decide to go that route anyway, there should be a function added called ConcreteAggregate::destroyIterator that deletes it (called in main).

cag_, ag, and cag all point to the same thing. That's what a shallow copy is. If cag_ is deleted, it will delete what cag points to.